# Sub category wrongly classified to root level and cannot be rectified

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am using SHS (Simple hierarchical select) which allows the user to create the child term under the parent term by themselves. For example:

root
--Canon  (parent level)
----5D3  (child level)

When I checked on the taxonomy list, I found those child levels are wrongly classified to root level, instead of their parent levels (the brand).

Even if I changed them to be under the brand manually, it was still keeping the previous hierarchical relationship after the action.

I checked the database and confirmed everything looked normal in {taxonomy_term__parent}, where they did connect to the correct parent term ID.

How comes this issue and how can I fix them?

Drupal version: 8.9

Comment: what happens if you disable the module and just use the normal hierarchical select that is in core ? does that work ?

Comment: @taggartJ Thanks! I dublicated my website and then had it disabled..with no luck, it didn't work. Those child terms are still under root level...

Comment: @taggartJ Their parent IDs look good in database, but the real relationship is wrong, which can be found at Relationship tab on /taxonomy/term/***/edit. So weird. Just wanted to know if it is controlled by somewhere else besides {taxonomy_term__parent}.

Comment: @taggartJ

Problem solved. It was because of the langcode in the database.

User created terms were all set as '1' instead of 'en'.

I fixed them by

UPDATE **** SET `langcode`= 'en'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It was because of the langcode in the database.

User created terms were all set as '1' instead of 'en'.

I fixed them by

```
UPDATE **** SET `langcode`= 'en'
```